# BeautifulSoup HTML parsing function won't work twice

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and bs4 to scrape a webpage. Here is a snippet of the Python script:

```
html = driver.page_source

soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

The first `print(soup)` returns the parsed html. The second `print(soup)` returns `[]`. Why is that? I'm quite new to scraping and Python in general, so any guidance here is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st expression you're rebindig `soup` to a parsed BeautifulSoup object:

```
soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
```

After the print, you are now calling this rebinded object (`soup`); e.g. a case of not the best chosen variable names?

What are your imports, where this `soup()` constructor comes from?
It's much more concise - and less error-prone - if you stick to the orthodox way of calling the constructor/creating the object - by using the `BeautifulSoup()` directly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# your code to get some html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you override your soup() function with a variable called "soup".

Try this out:

```
html = driver.page_source

soup_ = soup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup_)
soup_ = soup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup_)
```

Hopefully that helps you out!